# How to use launchctl for .ovpn file execution and dns

Tags: dns, macos-big-sur, openvpn

I am running BigSur OS.

Recently I was given an OpenVPN file to run a VPN.

When I execute this in the terminal I get

`➜  vpn sudo openvpn --config ./bpu-vpn.ovpn`

`Options error: --up script fails with '/usr/bin/update-systemd-resolved': No such file or directory (errno=2) Options error: Please correct this error. Use --help for more information`

`update-systemd-resolved` is a linux thing. Some google searches reveal that mac needs to use daemon via `launchd` on mac. But how to configure this, I am completely lost.

The VPN file tries to hit `/usr/bin/update-systemd-resolved` bash file in my system, of which there is none.

What is the way to manage this DNS issue with mac?